# Pass argument to a helper app in sandbox MacOS X <= 10.7.4

Tags: objective-c, macos, app-store, sandbox

I got the program and some helper apps in the bundle and need to pass argument to one of them. Now, i use Application Groups and common folder to share parameters. Its perfect works on Mac OS X >= 10.7.5, but there is no App Groups in earlier version and sandbox doesn't allow to pass arguments directly at launch.
So, how can i pass one (boolean) parameter to the helper application?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you launching the helper app?  Both `NSTask` and `posix_spawn()` allow arguments to be passed to the program, so I cannot see the difficulty.

Comment: @trojanfoe I use "launchApplicationAtURL". Cause helper app is Cocoa bundle too. Sandbox restriction  doesn't allow to pass parameters

Comment: Well depending on how the main and helper app communicate you can use `NSTask` to run `/usr/bin/open /path/to/helper/app --args arg1 arg2`.  I have successfully used `posix_spawn()` to create sub-processes within a sandbox app, so I don't understand why passing parameters is restricted.

Comment: @trojanfoe Its very strange. I tried to use open utility but there was the same problem: Arguments doesn't received by the helper. If i turn off the sandbox - helper receive

Comment: I have never heard of such a restriction and it's the simplest and most straight forward method of passing information to the helper app.

Comment: @trojanfoe but normally.. isn't a helper app run by launchd so it can run in bg? (please note im just asking :D)

Comment: @Daij-Djan If it's an XPC Service, then yes `launchd` will control it, however it can be an ordinary command line program or another OSX app.

Comment: I have only ever used `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` -- even with regular OSX Apps

Comment: If it works on 10.7.5 but not on 10.7.4: I have _never_ written code for or test code on anything but the latest version that Software Update delivers.

Comment: @trojanfoe On OS X 10.10 Yosemite, I am unable to pass any launch arguments to a helper application when sandboxed. NSTask, posix_spawn, AppleScript - nothing works. I can't believe there is no way to pass launch arguments when sandboxed anymore.

Comment: It does seem crazy to not be able to pass arguments. Apples sandbox seems to be a bit of a fail, as even in 10.11 they can' t get the Finder sandboxed. Indeed 2/3 of the processes are not sandboxed, those that are have many exceptions. I am using a complicated and fragile "look for the args in this common folder' system as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a simple bool I'd send the helper app a distributed notification.

your helper app could do nothing upon launch but wait for this notification

Comment: What's wrong with command line arguments?  Too simple and straight forward?

Comment: @Daij-Djan I tried to use notification. But its very unreliable. Sometimes it takes a lot of time for delivery and sometimes its even don't come

Comment: apple events? NSWorkspace can take apple events